# Should I be using BackgroundWorker or Threads for this?

Tags: c#, multithreading

All, I have used the `Thread` and `BackgroundWorker` classes with success to facilitate a smooth UI for a few small-scale applications. I have recently been given the job of converting a huge piece of code from serial to multi-threaded and I have some questions due to some comments I have seen on this very site. The code I have to convert makes a varying amount (usually a large number) of calls to SQL Server and these SQL queries can sometimes run for 30 minutes or so. As such, multi-threading is required.

I have already setup a test program using `BackgroundWorker` and these run well. However, some say that due to the `BackgroundWorker` using the Thread-Pool they should not be used for long running tasks. I have not read this anywhere (i.e. Joesph Albahari *C# 4.0 In a Nutshell*), and this contradicts [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx). Should I be using `BackgroundWorker` or `Thread` for such purposes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you consider using the Task Parallel Library?

Comment: possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343311/background-worker-process-or-thread

Comment: Any approach you you choose is going to deal with the thread pool. A process is only allowed a certain amount of threads by design. This is even true with a Task.  You also do not indicate where you heard this.

Comment: BackgroundWorker would be fine. BUT 30 minutes to run SQL query is too much - you should assign top priority to reduce it's length

Comment: I probably meant the *managed* Thread Pool. That is, the `BackgroundWorker` using this *Managed Thread Pool* would allow me to concentrate on on application tasks rather than thread management. I appreciate that 30 minutes is a long time but the use of the above two options for such tasks seems anything but clear cut and I would like to implement the multithreadding in the best way that is also commonly considered *best practice*...

Comment: @Johann Blais. I have not considered TPL as the majority of the end users will be running on desktops. Although most desktops are multicore this cannot be guaranteed (although that is not to say that the TPL cannot pseudo-parallelise the code for serial machine, but this offers no benefit in speed what-so-ever). Moreover, the type of work the application is doing is often scripted by the user. For some small scale users the act of parallelisation will slow the execution down.

Comment: @Killercam Also TPL's default behaviour runs tasks on the thread pool. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind the threadpool is that it reuses threads and thus amortizes the cost of creating new threads. Creating a thread may be a very expensive operation, so it makes sense reuse threads if possible. If you schedule long running jobs on the threadpool, you force it to create additional threads and thus reduce the benefit of reusing threads.

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of [asynchronous queries in ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756367%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Wow! I did not know you could do this. This is very useful. Thanks for the post... Although, my questions about threadding stands as it is not only SQL work that is done, and I will still require a seperate thread to keep the UI from freezing. Thanks again.

Comment: Indeed, this is useful and can reduce the amount of threads needed. However, as the other users suggested, 30 minutes for a query is really long. Maybe a look at the query plan can help to find index candidates or bottlenecks.

Comment: I appreciate it is long. But this is really not the issue. The data we are provide is some times of numerous columns of multi-million rows. This is just the state-of-affairs, and not down to poorly constructed DBs or queries. The level of aggregation that the end user requires means we some times have to deal with such DBs in this way. Ps. We use indexes on such tables, and they do speed up manipulations greatly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`BackgroundWorker` is appropriate to use for long-running tasks. It's threads from the `ThreadPool` that you shouldn't use for long-running tasks (`BackgroundWorker` does not use thread pool threads).

Also, a 30-minute SQL query is definitely a code smell. You might want to investigate what's going on there and see if you can speed things up.

**Edit:** I'm wrong - `BackgroundWorker` *does* use thread pool threads. I'm leaving this answer up for the discussion below.

Comment: BackgroundWorker calls `BeginInvoke` internally which I believe runs on the thread pool.

Comment: @Ilian: you might be right, although when I googled this issue I wasn't able to find any clear, authoritative (i.e. from Microsoft) statement of this. If BackgroundWorker *does* employ a thread pool thread, then the widespread advice of using BGW threads for long-running tasks is wrong.

Comment: The `BackgroundWorker` does use the *Managed Thread Pool* [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx). However, statements in the link above (i.e. "There are several scenarios in which it is appropriate to create and manage your own threads instead of using thread pool threads: 
...
You have tasks that cause the thread to block for long periods of time...". This contradict the points raised in the first few lines of [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx) - this is what has fuelled my question, the whole issue seems subjective.

Comment: @Hans: I'm not sure if I should delete my answer or not. It seems like the general advice on this topic is completely conflicted - you *should* use BGW for long-running tasks, but you *should not* use thread pool threads for long-running tasks.

Comment: Exactly. It is totally conflicted. I do not wish to embark upon a 10,000 - 15,000 lines of code translation using the wrong methodology that is not considered *best practice*. Note: The SQL tasks are so expensive as some will populate data sets of 10's of columns for 24 million rows+ (depending on the user's requirements). Hence the time taken for query execution.

Comment: I think the proper advice is to not use TP threads for threads that block often or block for a long time.  Like the OP's case.  That clogs up the pool, preventing other TP threads from starting in a timely manner.  Long running threads do that too but that's not a problem if they burn core.

Comment: @Hans: I don't think I follow you. You're saying it's OK to use a TP thread for a long-running task as long as that task is actually doing some work on the local machine? But it's not OK to use a TP thread when the task is basically just sitting and waiting for the server to finish?

Comment: @Hans Passant. So for my case, in which I have a verity of multi-minute jobs running sequentially (SQL queries and other data manipulations that can take second to hours, that can cause the UI to freeze), you reccomend *not* using BGW and to use the Thread class? The only down side to that is the ability to show the user what is occurring. A static but active UI, is just as bad (almost) as a dead one!? Thanks very much for your time lads.

Comment: I recommend you use SqlCommand.BeginExecuteXxxx() instead.  No thread required at all.  You cannot give reliable progress since you have no idea how long the query will take.  Use, say, a progress bar in marquee mode to give "I'm not dead" feedback.

Comment: I have found this quote, which seems to make sense to me: "Generally its advised not to use the background worker process for long running tasks, however this is not really a problem if you're only running one thread at a time." In an ideal world, I would probably create my own thread class based on the Event-Based Asynchronous Pattern, however this takes time and the BGW is already there flexing his guns...

Comment: The only thing is that it is not just SQL. I have other tasks that can also take time. I supose I could adopt the ADO.NET route you suggest for the SQL and a background worker based on my previous comment for everything else?

Answer (score 1):

The `ThreadPool` has a maximum number of active threads (`GetMaxThreads`/`SetMaxThreads`). Any tasks above that number will remain queued until a `ThreadPool` thread is available. For the purposes of this example, let's say that the max thread count is 10. If you spawn 10 queries through `BackgroundWorker` and each of them completes in 30 minutes, any other tasks queued on the `ThreadPool` will not run until after 30 minutes.

That task could just be a trivial tick from a `Timer` that updates a clock you have on the UI. This could be problematic since that clock could then be stuck for half an hour until a thread is available. Realistically though, `MaxThreads` is certainly greater than 10. Mine is 1023 (.NET 4, 2x2.26GHz laptop). So, hopefully you won't run into this issue if you decide to stick with `BackgroundWorker`. Still it's useful to understand why it's generally not advised to have long-running tasks on the `ThreadPool`.

Personally, I'd use dedicated threads just to be safe. Especially since the threads will certainly be idle while waiting for your queries to complete. The only advantage I see to using `BackgroundWorker` in your case is that it's easier to update a progress bar on the UI. But if you're not displaying the progress of your query, that's another reason to use dedicated threads.

Comment: Thanks for your time. The SQL queries are handelled sequentially by a script processor. This means I will ony ever be running one at a time (the results from one SQL query feed the subsequent ones). With this in mind and the point you make about BGW and the UI updates I will more than likely go with the BGW. However, Hans Passant makes a good point of using ADO.NET and `SqlCommand.BeginExecuteXxxx()` for the SQL stuff. Thanks again.